# Understanding MITM in an example authentication protocol

Tags: authentication, protocol-design, man-in-the-middle

Imagine that we have a protocol like this:
B -> A: R<sub>B</sub>
A -> B: {R<sub>B</sub>,B}<sub>K</sub>

Goal: authenticate A to B
K: a shared key between A and B
{}<sub>K</sub>: encrypting by K

After receiving {R<sub>B</sub>, B}<sub>K</sub> by B, B is able to authenticate A. But what if we have something like:
A -> C: {R<sub>B</sub>,B}<sub>K</sub>
C -> B: {R<sub>B</sub>,B}<sub>K</sub>
so in this case B will authenticate C instead of A, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

In the question's example, C is acting a Man-in-the-Middle (MitM), impersonating B with respect to A (at the communication level) when receiving {R<sub>B</sub>,B}<sub>K</sub>, and impersonating A with respect to B (similarly) when sending {R<sub>B</sub>,B}<sub>K</sub>. Absent measures not described, B will accept the message {R<sub>B</sub>,B}<sub>K</sub> sent by C as if it came directly from A.

Such possibility of a MitM is a standard hypothesis in cryptography and protocol design, because it's it's physically possible in the overwhelming majority of communication means in use today: wires, optical fiber, radio (including satellite).

Whether "B will authenticate C instead of A" is a matter of convention and context, and these vary.

Absent other attack¹, the protocol insures that A participated in the exchange, and I would not say that the authentication property of the protocol limited to what's described in the question² is broken or useless. For example if A is a remote control for a device B, then the remote was involved within the time period between generating R<sub>B</sub> and accepting {R<sub>B</sub>,B}<sub>K</sub>. If further B verifies that this time period is as most $t$, then B has the insurance A is within distance $t\,c/2$, where $c$ is the speed of light.

---

¹ Attacks are possible or not depending on properties of the encryption used, and on how parties with knowledge of key K (including A and B) use it beyond what's described in the question.

² Things would be quite different if the question ended in: having authenticated A, B proceeds to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem in this question is understanding the authentication correctly.
If B wants to authenticate A, it means B must receive adequate evidence of message authentication and entity authentication from A.

```
A -> C: {RB,B}K
C -> B: {RB,B}K
```

In this scheme, on one hand, C is just acting like a wire, and on the other hand, B is receiving enough evidence of message authentication and entity authentication from A.